# Changing decimal separator in existing columns in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

In LibreOffice Calc, if I have a column with a lot of numbers in this format `8,1` *(comma)*, how  can I transfer all these numbers to the format `8.1` *(dot)*?

When I say "a lot" I mean thousands of numbers, so it is just impossible to rewrite it again in the right format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the *Edit*, and select *Find & Replace*.

Under *Search for*, put `,`- and under *Replace with*, put `.`. Then press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

--For ubuntu system:
Go to System Setting -> Language Support - Regional Format -> "Display numbers, date and currency amounts in the used format for:"
and choose your local system.

[image: Language Support Settings]