# How can I change the decimal separator for my locale?

Tags: libreoffice, locale

I want to change the decimal separator of my system from "," to ".". I have edited the respective locale file `/usr/share/i18n/locales/` and added these lines:

```
LC_NUMERIC
decimal_point   "<U002E>"
thousands_sep   "<U002C>"
grouping        3;3
END LC_NUMERIC
```

Then, I ran :

```
sudo locale-gen
```

I have rebooted my computer and run:

```
locale -k LC_NUMERIC
```

and I get:

```
decimal_point="."
thousands_sep=","
grouping=3;3
numeric-decimal-point-wc=46
numeric-thousands-sep-wc=44
numeric-codeset="UTF-8"
```

However, if I go to LibreOffice Calc, I see the numbers are still formated with "," as the decimal separator. Why is this?

Also, I'm not satisfied with answers given in [Changing decimal separator in existing columns in LibreOffice Calc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431713/changing-decimal-separator-in-existing-columns-in-libreoffice-calc). I don't want to simply "Find & Replace" commas for dots because I got functions in my LibreOffice Calc documents that won't work if I replace commas for dots (because numbers are no more recognized as numbers). I also don't want to change all the language settings of my system, just the decimal separator.

I am using Ubuntu-MATE 16.04

`uname -a`:

```
Linux nesper94-E402MA 3.14.77-031477-generic #201608200632 SMP Sat Aug 20 10:34:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: In the example picture you provided the decimal separator is the dot "." as you seem to have intended. (ejemplo) Also what settings do you have in Libreoffice Options--> Language Settings --> Language?

Comment: Did you *add* those lines? There was reasonably

Comment: @Bruni You're right about the picture, suppose I was very sleepy. In LibreOffice settings: 

User interface: English (USA)

Locale setting: Default - Spanish (Colombia)

Decimal separator key: Same as locale setting (,)

Comment: Have you changed these settings? This should work.(you will have to restart Libreoffice afterwards)

Comment: @Bruni Yes, I have changed for example "Locale setting" to English (EE. UU.) and it does change the decimal separator to "." ...but that's the point, I don't want to change all my settings, just the decimal separator. Changing the locale file I'm using should work, but it doesn't, it seems like LibreOffice use it's own locale files and not the system's locale files or something. Thanks for your interest and help.

Answer (score 1):

Copied `/usr/share/i18n/locales/sv_SE` to `.../sv_SE_std-comma`
Then edited `.../sv_SE` 'in place' and copied to `.../sv_SE_dp`

```
$ diff -u2 /usr/share/i18n/locales/sv_SE_dp /usr/share/i18n/locales/sv_SE_std-comma 
--- /usr/share/i18n/locales/sv_SE_dp    2020-12-30 21:06:07.959649184 +0100
+++ /usr/share/i18n/locales/sv_SE_std-comma 2020-12-30 19:21:36.726778749 +0100
@@ -196,6 +196,6 @@
 
 LC_NUMERIC
-decimal_point           "."
-thousands_sep           " "
+decimal_point           ","
+thousands_sep           ""
 grouping                3;3
 END LC_NUMERIC

$ sudo locale-gen 
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
- - - 8<---
  sv_SE.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.

$ locale -k LC_NUMERIC
decimal_point="."
thousands_sep=" "
grouping=3;3
numeric-decimal-point-wc=46
numeric-thousands-sep-wc=32
numeric-codeset="UTF-8"

$
```

Now LibreOffice Calc accepts numbers with decimal point,
entered with a deci-point from the numeric keypad `Del/,`-key

Nice!